# How do I make a website look like the PARCC?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to add a "math editor" like the ones on the PARCC Online Math Tests. [Here is an image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKtTa.png)

I'm mostly interested in that box with the symbols. It basically lets the person write a math symbol (radical, fractions, exponents, etc.) in the box above it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

PS I don't know if I'm in the right place. I was told to try to come here from a different forum. I'm sorry for sloppiness.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: That "other forum" is incorrect unfortunately. There may be other sites in the StackExchange network that your question may be more suited to, though.

Comment: If that's an image from your browser, press F12 then check the elements and the sources. Otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=math+editor

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I did what Yezzz suggested and I think I'm a step closer. It looks like, from the Developer Tools page, the line that changes is ARIA line (which I don't know what that is, currently). But thanks for the suggestion.